# How to copy a bone world space location to an empty on all frames?

Tags: animation, keyframes, inverse-kinematics

I have a bone that is animated. It has keyframes on all the frames of the timeline. I need to add to that bone an IK target (empty object) that plays the same animation of the bone before it was assigned to that IK.

So I added an empty object, and parented it to that bone (bone parenting only, not IK). Now that object moves with that bone.

Now I want to insert a keyframe on all the frames for that empty so that its location is tracked (while being parented). In other words I want to copy the bone world space location to that empty object on all the frames.
After that I want to unparent that empty object in the hope that it remains animated. Then I can assign it as an IK to the bone.

But I am not able to copy the animation of the bone to the empty.

I tried copying the keyframes of the bone to the empty object (in the graph editor), but the empty snaps to the world origin because the copied keyframes are relative to the bone local position which is (0, 0, 0,).

I tried to bake the empty object while being parented. It is inserting a keyframe on all its frame like i wanted but when it's unparented it's staying in it's place and not recreating the bones animation.

**How to copy that bones animation to the empty object without it being parented to the bone ?**

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to bake the animation on the visual keyframes. It added a keyframe on all the timeline for the empty object based on its visual location and rotation.